# Mongodb get users ranking based on their contributions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the rough representation of my mongodb collection:

```
{
   user: ID1,
   type: 'redemption,
   amount: 200
},
{
   user: ID2,
   type: 'redemption,
   amount: 1000
},
{
   user: ID1,
   type: 'redemption',
   amount: 300
},
{
   user: ID3,
   type: 'redemption',
   amount: 3000
}
```

"type" field is variable (redemption, transfer, etc...). What I am struggling with is to find what users redeemed the most amount of points. In this particular case, ID3 is the top redeemer with 3000 points, ID2 is the second (1000) and ID1 is the third (300+200=500).

What Mongo operations should I be looking at?

p.s. I am kind of getting there:

```
aggregate([ 
            { 
                $group : { 
                    _id : "$user",
                    redeemedTotal: { $sum: "$amount" }
                } 
            } 
        ])
```

But it $sum **not only** type: 'redemption' but other type of amounts. How do I narrow it down to just `type: 'redemption'`

p.p.s. I think I got it:

```
 .aggregate([ 
        {
            $match: { "type": "redemption" }
        },
        { 
            $group : { 
                _id : "$sender",
                redeemedTotal: { $sum: "$amount" }
            } 
        } 
    ])
```

Comment: Yes as if you only care about `type: redemption`, certainly what you've done is right using a `$match` stage as first stage would help you to lessen the data for further stages, As it is straight forward & since it's already self achieved you can actually delete/close this question..Also isn't this `_id : "$sender"` be `_id : "$user"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$cond` operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      redeemedTotal: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: ["$type", "redemption"]
            },
            "$amount", //true
            0 //false
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YnhD5L6TPyk)

## Alternative

Groupby more than 1 field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        user: "$user",
        type: "$type"
      },
      redeemedTotal: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hc7ImKG8F3S)